# Calling original inherited function after overriding it

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, overriding, private

I am trying to modify a private member of a class which was inherited from the base class. The problem is that in the derived class, I am overriding the method that sets the private member. In the code below, I want to modify both _a._time and b._time, using the overridden method setTime.

Base class

```
class timeClass
{
    public:
        void setTime(double time){ _time = time;}
        double getTime(){ return _time;}
    private:
        double _time;
}
```

Inhereted class 1

```
class a : public timeClass
{
    public:
        void doStuff(){ }
    private:
        double things;
}
```

Inhereted class 2

```
class bClass : public timeClass
{
    public:
        void setTime(double time)
        {
           _time = time; //can't access _time since its private
           _a.setTime = time;
        }
    private:
        aClass _a;
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how yo should do it:

```
void setTime(double time)
{
   timeClass::set_time(_time);
// ^^^^^^^^^^^
// Will invoke the base class's set_time() function

   _a.setTime(time);
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//    Will invoke setTime() on the `_a` subobject
}
```

Comment: For some reason, _a._time is not updated when I run b.setTime(1.0); I can't post any more code, but do you have any wild guesses what could be happening?

Comment: @dead_jake: Hard to tell. I suggest you asking a new question and posting the relevant code